# Как удалить фрагмент, вызванный в активити, по клику по кнопке, расположенной во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть активити, и есть view, вложенное в это активити. При клике по этому view, появляется фрагмент:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.land:
                metods.moveToCenter(land, 1000, 2000, 3);
                fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);

                if (fragment == null) {
                    fragment = new FragmentGoToStage();
                    fm.beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
                            .commit();
                }
```

В самом фрагменте `FragmentGoToStage` есть кнопка `back_button`, при клике на которую этот фрагмент должен удалятся из активити.

Как запрограммировать событие, когда клик по `back_button` удаляет фрагмент из активити?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ:

Вызвать во фрагменте

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Правильный способ:

Фрагменты не должны управлять собой или другими фрагментами. Нужно при клике передавать это событие в активити через интерфейс и уже активити решает, что делать с фрагментом.

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;
...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnArticleSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
...
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Append the clicked item's row ID with the content provider Uri
        Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArticleColumns.CONTENT_URI, id);
        // Send the event and Uri to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(noteUri);
    }
...
    public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(Uri articleUri);
    }
}
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks).

Comment: честно говоря, глядя на второй способ, возникает желание отказаться от этой идеи в принципе) Первый способ не сработал. Сработало вот так: в самом фрагменте в onClickListener button  public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayout);
                fm.beginTransaction()
                        .remove(fragment)
                        .commit();
            } });

Comment: но плюсую Ваш ответ авансом, т.к. надеюсь, что второй способ должен  сработать :-)